# Question on circles inscribed in a rectangle

Tags: geometry, circles, rectangles

In rectangle $ABCD$, $AB = 8$ and $BC = 20$. Let $P$ be a point on $AD$ such that angle $\measuredangle BPC = 90^\circ$. If $r_1, r_2, r_3$ are the radii of the incircles of triangles $APB, BPC$ and $CPD$, what is the value of $r_1 + r_2 + r_3$?

Comment: Do you have any work to show?

Comment: *P* lies of the circle whose diameter is *BC*.

Comment: @GaussTheBauss I find area of rectangle to be 160 so area of triangle $BPC=80$.Let the height and base of triangle $BPC$ be $a , b$ respectively. so $(1/2)ab=80$.and $a^2+b^2={20}^2$.from this we can find raddi of $r_2$.Only this!!

Comment: From the 2 equations setup, a and b can be found. If $r_2$ can be found (by your method) because 3 sides of $\triangle BPC$ are known, you can use the same trick to find $r_1$ and $r_3$.

Comment: @Mick In triangle $BPC$ we know the sum of $a+b$

Comment: I think you can also find their difference a - b. Hence find a and then b.

Comment: @Mick yes of course I think a=8*root5 and b=4*root5

Comment: Then you can proceed to find $r_1$ and $r_2$. But I think (I don't know yet) there is a more elegant way of finding that sum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33430/discussion-between-ayushakj-and-mick).

Comment: my hint: radius of incircle of a triangle $=area\ / \ semiperimeter$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the inradius equation for a [right triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RightTriangle.html), as hinted by @Joey, just replace the variables:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
r_1 &=& \frac{AB + AP - BP}{2} \\
r_2 &=& \frac{CD + DP - CP}{2} \\
    &=& \frac{AB + (BC - AP) - CP}{2} \\
r_3 &=& \frac{BP + CP - BC}{2} \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

And then simplify:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
R &=& r_1 + r_2 + r_3 \\
  &=& \frac{AB + AP - BP}{2} +
              \frac{AB + (BC - AP) - CP}{2} +
              \frac{BP + CP - BC}{2} \\
  &=& AB \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So the total radii of the incircles is 8.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the side lengths of a right triangle, with $c$ the length of the hypotenuse, then the radius of the incircle is given by
$$ r = \frac{a+b-c}{2}. $$
One way to see this is to realize that the radius in this case is equal to the length of the tangent from the right angle vertex to the incircle, and do a bit of fairly simple algebra to get the result, noting that the length of two tangents from a point are equal.

Another way to see this is the following: Note that the area of a triangle is given by $rs$, where $s$ is the semi-perimeter, and in the case of a right triangle, it is also $\frac{1}{2}ab$. We thus have
$$ rs = A = \frac{ab}{2}\implies r = \frac{ab}{2s} = \frac{ab}{a+b+c}. $$
Note that
$$ a+b+c = \frac{(a+b)^2 - c^2}{a+b - c} = \frac{a^2+b^2+ 2ab-c^2}{a+b-c} = \frac{2ab}{a+b-c}$$
and hence
$$ r = ab\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2ab}\right) = \frac{a+b-c}{2} $$
as desired. Now, each of the triangles in question are right triangles, and the side lengths can be calculated, so the answer can be found using this relation.